# 'unordered_map' file not found error when compiling with Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11

A file in my project fails to compile with

`'unordered_map' file not foundIn file included from ...`

This is despite I compile with -std=c++ and a directory that has unordered_map in it is in system include paths.

`clang -std=c++14 -x c++ -v -E /dev/null`

results in the output below. `/Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1` does contain `unordered_map`.

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
"/Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.11.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name null -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 264.3.102 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.3.0 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++14 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/ovz -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.11.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o - -x c++ /dev/null
clang -cc1 version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) default target x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here: 
#include <...> search starts here: /Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
/usr/local/include
/Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.3.0/include
/Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

Comment: Did you `#include` as `"unordered_map"` or as `<unordered_map>`?

Comment: Have you tried `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: @Leon It is <unordered_map>

Comment: @Danh Looks like this solved it. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass this option:

```
-stdlib=libc++
```

to select [`libc++`](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

I heard people said that `AppleClang` uses an old version of `libstdc++` (probably from `g++`) by default. I'm not sure why they made that decision (needless to say, it's understandable in `GNU/Linux` because most of the time, `GNU/Linux` is shipped with `libstdc++` from `g++`).